# Login Session doesn't work first time

Tags: php

I'm having trouble with the login session. It's working perfectly fine but the only issue is it doesn't work for the first time when I login, instead it keeps on loading until I login the second time. Below is the code of login session. Please help me out in it.

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$error=''; 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
else
{

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12345");

$username = stripslashes($username);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);

$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);

$query = mysql_query("select * from login where password='$password' AND username='$username'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows == 1) {
$_SESSION['login_user']=$username;
echo "Login Successfully";
header('Refresh: 3; ../packages/package.php');; 
} else {
$error = "Username or Password is invalid";
}
mysql_close($connection);
}
}
?>
```

session.php

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12345");
// Selecting Database
$db = mysql_select_db("company", $connection);
session_start();
// Storing Session
$user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

$ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
$login_session =$row['username'];
if(!isset($login_session)){
mysql_close($connection);
header('Location: index.php');
}
?>
```

login_page.php

```
<?php

include('login.php'); 

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: ../index.php");
}
?>
```

Comment: session must be started inside all pages using sessions

Comment: Are you sure the refresh isn't showing a cached page in the browser?

Comment: well ive tried that too, like i included session_start(); in index.php but it is displaying error as
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in C:\xampp\htdocs\jobmonster\member\login.php on line 2

Comment: #benJ - it is just loading for the first time i login but it doesn't redirect until i login it the second time.

Comment: Also, update MySQL to ***MySQLi*** . MySQL is deprecated, and really, **REALLY** should be scrapped and developed into the MySQL*improved*

Comment: #Martin, i didn't receive your answer, and yes ill update that one soon...

Comment: no one has yet answered me my question. :|

Comment: Not sure but maybe `header('Refresh: 3; ../packages/package.php');;` is the reason it "keeps on loading".

Comment: even tried removing the header too, but it didn't work!